# Fitting a spline: find coefficients using Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, regression, convolution, spline

I came up with a idea to estimate the coefficients of a B-spline fit by using the Fourier Transform but I don't know if it makes any sense to estimate them in this way.

Given that

$$s(x)=\sum_kc(k)\beta^n(x-k)$$ where $k$ is an integer and $\beta^n(x)$ is defined as a ($n+1$) times convolution :$$\beta_0*\beta_0*...*\beta_0(x)$$ 
where $\beta_0$ is a rectangular pulse of length 1 centred at zero.

One could hence write $s(x)=(c*\beta^n)(x)$.
Applying the Fourier Transform we obtain.
$s(\omega)=c(\omega)\cdot \beta^n(\omega)=c(\omega)\cdot \beta_0(\omega)^{n+1}$

From here I would like to obtain $c(\omega)$ to then apply the inverse FFT.
I've seen some papers dealing with a similar methodology but without explaining in detail what are the condition in order for this to work.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance